# Nginx location try_files with add_header redirect and cors

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect requests to index.php to enable pretty links, using try_files works for this however I can not seem to get try_files and add_headers to work at the same time

my current location block looks like this:

```
location /api/v1/ {

        try_files $uri /sephaku/api/v1/index.php?$query_string;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://0.0.0.0:9000';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';


    }
```

But the Headers don't seem to have been added.

I have tried adding an if statement like so:

```
if ($request_method = 'GET') { }
```

With my headers inside of it. In this case the headers work but the redirect does not.

Comment: As soon as nginx goes to `/index.php` it forgets everything in this location. So all your `add_headers` are useless, you have to add them to the location where `index.php` is processed.

Comment: Thanks Alexey I ended up including the more_set_headers module and implementing them before the location block, but your solution seems more elegant.

Comment: You must add "always" to nginx config file.
Did you try this? https://serverfault.com/questions/785251/nginx-try-files-addheader-doesnt-work

Comment: Here's a solution for PHP sites: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371789/1718491

Comment: @user3804427 adding `always` will not resolve the `try_files` problem.