# nginx add_header on specific URI to PHP app with front controller

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, nginx-location

I have a pretty standard setup with a symfony2-like app with a front controller, running on nginx 1.10 and Centos7. It all works as expected, blocks where expected etc.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /opt/my/code/web;
    index app.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to php5-fpm
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {

        # problem here
        location ~ ^/recording {
            add_header Content-Type audio/x-wav;
        }

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/?.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

I have a few issues but the main one is that I want special handling for a URI matching `/recording` but it still has to go through the front controller. (This is not debatable, it HAS to go through the front controller and modify a response header if the URI matches `/recording`)

Since `try_files` redirects to `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$)` nginx's `$uri` parameter used for location matching gets updated to `/app.php`, so any nested locations won't work.

I cant use `add_header` outside of the front controller block because any `add_header` directives get dropped on an internal redirect.

Obviously I can't use `location if` with `add_header` either.

This is easy in apache, but the only remote solution I have found uses a third party lua module and the installation docs are a bit thin on that and the thought of compiling that in from source on centos is giving me heart palpitations.

Comment: in my case specifically i gave up, it just wouldn't work, so I just mordernized this code https://gist.github.com/Erutan409/8e774dfb2b343fe78b14#file-mimetype-php and set the mime type using file extensions before response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If internal redirect bother us, lets remove internal redirect :) You can solve it easy with fastcgi config duplication

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /opt/my/code/web;
    index app.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/recording {
        add_header Content-Type audio/x-wav;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app.php;
    }    

    # pass the PHP scripts to php5-fpm
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/?.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Second solution works only if you know content type of all other requests. We can use variables. (*btw, I don't suggest this solution because harder to support and not cute :)*)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /opt/my/code/web;
    index app.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
        set $ct "text/html";
    }

    location ~ ^/recording {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
        set $ct "audio/x-wav";
    }    

    # pass the PHP scripts to php5-fpm
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/?.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        add_header "Content-Type $ct;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is elegant enough, not that I like the duplication, but screw it. I can also get clever with the location matching and stack location blocks if I need more special handling at some point

Comment: It's almost official point of nginx dev team: *Duplicate it! If too many duplication - use includes or external template system*. Probably because it's helps to keep config parser simpler.
I edited my post, was wrong fastcgi_param.

Comment: if it was official i would say link it, becasue thats a VERY important thing to know.

Comment: As I said, "almost official", because not documented but based on many answers in nginx mail lists by Igor Sysoev, Maxim Dounin. etc. So hard to link it.