# Directive add_header ignored when try_files to named location

Tags: nginx, proxy, header, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

NGINX version: nginx/1.15.12

I am trying to add a cache control header into a location block, which has an try_files towards a named location. Unfortunately it seems that add_header directive is ignored, even when add_header has ***always*** added.

From the docs, I saw the directives must be inherited from the previous config level if there is no add_header directive in the current one. Since in the end the current one will be ***@proxy*** location, which has no add_header directives, I can not understand why these are not added from the parent locations.

> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

Less talk, more code ( config in this case ) :

```
http {
    error_log /dev/stdout info;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;

    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 620s;

    server_tokens off;

    server {
        access_log /dev/stdout main;

        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name test;

        # brotli
        brotli off;
        brotli_static on;
        brotli_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/json application/javascript image/svg+xml;

        # gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_min_length 500;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 7;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/json application/javascript image/svg+xml;

        location @proxy {
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            proxy_send_timeout 60s;

            rewrite ^(.*)$ /whatever/test/path/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html @proxy;

            # keep the cache for 20 seconds
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=20";
        }

        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri @proxy;

            # keep the cache for a long time years
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=63113904, immutable";
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I managed to fix this by creating a separate file with the proxy config which I import in each location which contains the add_header directive, but I want to find if there is another better solution for my case. If necessary, I can provide the current fix config for better understanding.

Comment: The previous configuration level is the `server` block. In your configuration, just move the `add_header` to the `server` block level, and it will be inherited by two `location` blocks. The other `location` block with its own `add_header` directive will not inherit.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964572/nginx-location-try-files-with-add-header-redirect-and-cors#comment53754909_32964572

Comment: Also if you're running a PHP site like WordPress this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371789/1718491